# PHP base_convert in Java

Tags: java, php

Is there a good method to convert between bases in Java in a fashion compatible with PHP's `base_convert` function? I've been playing around with boolean arrays, but it seems like a really complicated solution to this problem.

Comment: Numeric bases? How about the [parse method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) on `Integer`? There's also a corresponsing [`toString` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)).

Comment: @BoristheSpider This **is** actually the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling and a suggestion by @BoristheSpider, this answer seems to work correctly, including having the same overflow problems related to 32 bit integers as in PHP.

```java
/**
 * Converts a string from one base to another base. The bases must be between
 * 2 and 36 inclusive. This function exhibits the same issues as the original
 * PHP version related to overflow in 32 bit integers.
 * 
 * @param inputValue A string representation of a number.
 * @param fromBase The starting radix of a number between 2 and 36 inclusive.
 * @param toBase The ending radix of the number between 2 and 36 inclusive.
 * @return The <code>inputValue</code> converted into <code>toBase</code> base.
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php
 */
public static String base_convert(final String inputValue, final int fromBase, final int toBase) {
    if (fromBase < 2 || fromBase > 36 || toBase < 2 || toBase > 36) {
        return null;
    }
    String ret = null;
    try {
        ret = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(inputValue, fromBase), toBase);
    } catch(Exception ex) {};
    return ret;
}
```

And for bonus points, this function can be easily wrapped to provide PHP's `bindec` and `decbin` functionality:

```java
/**
 * Converts a decimal string into a binary string.
 * 
 * @param inputValue A string representation of a decimal number.
 * @return A bit string representation of the <code>inputValue</code>.
 */
public static String decbin(final String inputValue) {
    return Util.base_convert(inputValue, 10, 2);
}
/**
 * Converts a binary string into a decimal string.
 * 
 * @param inputValue A string representation of a binary number.
 * @return A decimal number string representation of the <code>inputValue</code>.
 */
public static String bindec(final String inputValue) {
    return Util.base_convert(inputValue, 2, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
  public static String base_convert(final String inputValue, final int fromBase, final int toBase) {
    return new BigInteger(inputValue, fromBase).toString(toBase);
  }
```

Looks more "the java way" for me :)

Comment: But it doesn't implement the "bugs" in php's base convert, so the behavior is similar, but not identical.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @jwriteclub.

but sometimes we need replace nonnumeric.

```
    public static String base_convert(final String inputValue, final int fromBase, final int toBase) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(inputValue))
        return inputValue;

    if (fromBase < 2 || fromBase > 36 || toBase < 2 || toBase > 36) {
        return null;
    }
    String ret = null;

    final String numberInputValue = inputValue.replaceAll("\\D", "");

    try {
        Integer in=Integer.parseInt(numberInputValue, fromBase);
        ret = Integer.toString(in, toBase);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return ret;
}
```